# Acceptance rates of submitted papers by country

Tags: publications, writing

Is there any data source or statistic showing acceptance rate of submitted papers for publication by country?

Comment: What would the country be if there are multiple authors from different countries?

Comment: @MaartenBuis Count the paper for all countries

Comment: Your best best for computer science conferences is the PC chair's PowerPoint presentation at the business meeting.  PC Chairs often jokingly display acceptance rates by country (or even US state) of submission, research focus, number of authors, keywords in the title, minutes between first submission and the deadline, number of math expressions in the abstract, authors' academic ranks ....  Nobody takes them seriously, and they are quickly forgotten.  But sometimes you can still find the slides on the web.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/120109/does-country-of-author-influence-the-rejection-of-research-paper

Comment: See p. 13 https://research.ipmu.jp/seminar/sysimg/seminar/2133.pdf